# Async/await kotlin coroutines from blocking code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I'm use Spring boot without reactive Web.

I try to run some async request with Kotlin coroutines

```kotlin
    @GetMapping
    fun test(): Message {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        return runBlocking {
            val hello = async { hello(restTemplate) }
            val world = async { world(restTemplate) }
            Message("${hello.await()} ${world.await()}!")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun world(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
        logger.info("Getting WORLD")
        return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/world", World::class.java).body!!.payload
    }

    private suspend fun hello(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
        logger.info("Getting HELLO")
        return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/hello", Hello::class.java).body!!.payload
    }
```

But this code runs sequentially.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `restTemplate.getForEntity` a suspend function?

Comment: No. This is not suspend fun

Comment: Just marking a function as suspend doesn't make it suspend-able or asynchronous, another side-effect is `runBlocking` is single-threaded so single-thread will start first then get blocked and then only second request will happen. You have to wrap blocking calls using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /* Blocking Call */ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is work in parallel:

```kotlin
    @GetMapping
    fun test(): Message {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        return runBlocking {
            val hello = async { hello(restTemplate) }
            val world = async { world(restTemplate) }
            Message("${hello.await()} ${world.await()}!")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun world(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
        logger.info("Getting WORLD")
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/world", World::class.java).body!!.payload
        }
    }

    private suspend fun hello(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
        logger.info("Getting HELLO")
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/hello", Hello::class.java).body!!.payload
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code runs in parallel. But I found that I cannot get restTemplate to get both responses at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**
Use `async` with a custom Dispatcher such as `Dispatchers.IO` designed to offload blocking IO.

```kotlin
val hello = async(Dispatchers.IO) { hello(restTemplate) }
val world = async(Dispatchers.IO) { world(restTemplate) }
```

**Update:**
I was informed in the [Kotlin coroutines slack channel](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C1CFAFJSK/p1627974693048300), that I can use `async(Dispatchers.IO)` rather than using `async` + `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

<s>I took @Sergey Nikulitsa code and created an extension function that takes a lambda with a receiver (similar to `async`) to combine both `async` and `withContext(Dispatches.IO)`.</s>

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun <T> CoroutineScope.myRestTemplateAsync(
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): Deferred<T> {

    return async(Dispatchers.IO, start) {
        block() 
    }
}
```

Then it can be used in your code like so:

```kotlin
@GetMapping
fun test(): Message {
    val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
    return runBlocking {
        val hello = myRestTemplateAsync { hello(restTemplate) }
        val world = myRestTemplateAsync { world(restTemplate) }
        Message("${hello.await()} ${world.await()}!")
    }
}

private suspend fun world(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
    logger.info("Getting WORLD")
    return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/world", World::class.java).body!!.payload
}

private suspend fun hello(restTemplate: RestTemplate): String {
    logger.info("Getting HELLO")
    return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/hello", Hello::class.java).body!!.payload
}
```

### Preliminary results

**At this point, I am just experimenting with this method** and I am using Spring WebMVC only and RestTemplate for 5+ calls.

The `myRestTemplateAsync` extension function **has consistently reduced execution times between 30% and 50% compared to its synchronous counterpart**.

### Why this works over just using `async { }`?

For the RestTemplate specifically, using `async {...}` within the `coroutineScope` didn't seem to make a difference, and executions times were at par with the synchronous code.

Furthermore, looking at the threads in the profiler, there was no "Dispatcher Workers" created when using async by itself. This leads me to believe that the thread-per-request model of the RestTemplate was blocking the entire thread.

When a new dispatcher is specified in `async`, it shifts the execution of the coroutine (and the function `block`) to a new thread in the `Dispatchers.IO` thread pool.

In this case, the code-block should contain the RestTemplate call (a single call). As far as I can tell, this prevents the RestTemplate from blocking the original context.

### Why you may want to use this method?

If you have been using RestTemplate (thread-per-request model) in a large project, it could be a difficult task to just replace it with a non-blocking client like WebClient. With this, you can continue to use most of your code, and simply add the `myRestTemplateAsync` in areas of your code where you could make multiple calls asynchronously.

**If you are starting a new project don't use `RestTemplate`. Instead is best to use [WebFlux with coroutines in Kotlin as explained in this article](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow).**

### Is this a good idea?

At this time, I don't have enough information to say one way or the other. I hope to run more extensive tests and evaluate:

- Memory consumption under load
- Possible thread pool exhaustion under load
- How are exceptions propagated and handled

If you have any comments on why this may or may not be a good idea, please post them below.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe root cause is:

- restTemplate use java.io (not java.nio)
- restTemplate block current thread until it gets HTTP response
- coroutines magic don't work in this case

Solution:

- Using http-client that use java.nio

Answer (score 0):

- `runBlocking`: It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.
- Here we create a `CoroutineScope` by using [coroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) method. This function is designed for parallel decomposition of work. When any child coroutine in this scope fails, this scope fails and all the rest of the children are cancelled.
- Because [coroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) is suspend function, so we mark `fun test()` as `suspend fun` (Suspend functions are only allowed to be called from a coroutine or another suspend function). By using `CoroutineScope` object, we can call `async` and `launch` to start a coroutine

```kotlin
  @GetMapping
  suspend fun test(): Message {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        return coroutineScope {
            val hello = async { hello(restTemplate) }
            val world = async { world(restTemplate) }
            Message("${hello.await()} ${world.await()}!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maye you could add some text to explain why this works? Having code is nice, but it is not self-evident for people who might not already know.

Comment: Spring Framework don't allow to use suspend functions for a rest-controllers (out of the box)

Comment: implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")

Comment: Basically spring-boot-starter-webflux brings support for suspened functions.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines